# XAMPP PHP 5.6 enable PDO MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I can't get PDO MSSQL working on XAMPP with PHP 5.6.3. XAMPP is installed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. I added the following line to php.ini and of course I downloaded that most recent file from Microsoft and copied it to the extensions directory.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

As described here: [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I also installed the Microsoft ODBC driver on the machine. I restarted Apache several times now and still don't have any kind of information about PDO MSSQL within phpinfo().

I'll appreciate your hints guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the sqlsrv_* extension, mssql is deprecated: [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

EDIT: I realised you're already using sqlsrv. Not mssql. I used [this](http://bendustries.co/wp/setting-up-xampp-to-work-with-mssql/) tutorial to set it up with Xampp, and seemed to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the link JohnnyBell but I think I already described that everything that is in that tutorial is already in place. Well, ok, I added the sql native client (even though it's not on the documentation of MS), but nothing changed, it doesn't tell me anything about sqlsrv within phpinfo.

Comment: In your OP you have stated you only pasted one line in the .ini file. Have you made sure both lines are there? extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll & extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that, yes, I have both in there:
`code` extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll and 
`code` extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Errors are:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

And to be honest: if I run phpinfo from XAMPP a cannot see anything that relates to sqlsrv...

Comment: Have you ensured both .dll files are in the \ext directory?

Comment: Yes, definitely, I extracted the downloaded exe from Microsoft directly to the \ext directory, so all files are in there...

Comment: Can you show me how you're attempting to connect to the database? You can blank out the credentials, I just need an example.

Comment: I had a spark of hope as MS is stating that 3.2 version of the sqlsrv driver only works with 3.2 PHP 5.6.4+ and upgraded my xampp to 5.6.8 but it didn't helped and still doesn't work.

My code is pretty simple: `code`try{
   $DBH = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$MSSQLServer;database=$MSSQLDB;", $MSSQLUser, $MSSQLDB);  
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Error: <br>";
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}

Comment: Would it be out of the question to do a fresh install of the xampp server and drivers? Also, what architecture is your OS?

Comment: php error logs says: 
[28-Apr-2015 15:22:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[28-Apr-2015 15:22:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

--> which is weird, as both files are definitely there.

edit/ OS is WinServer 2012 R2 (and therefore x64)

edit/ the upgrade I was talking about in fact was a complete uninstall - install

Comment: This could be a compatibility issue. There's no x64 release of the sqlsrv extension. You'll need to check that the VC++ version you have installed is x86. I have a feeling this is the issue.

Comment: Where do you have the information from? On https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx Windows Server 2012 R2 is listed as compatible (and WinServer 2012 is not available as x86)

Comment: The Operating System is compatible, sure. But you need to install Visual C++ Redist x86 version on your server. The extension is built with 32bit architecture: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: JohnnyBell, that's basically it! 2012 Redist (x86) wasn't installed, it is working now. Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the PHP path C:\xampp\php to the Environment Variables in Windows 2008 R2